# second main class overwrites first main class during maven build

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm still working on a single maven project with two main classes. I'm now using profiles and the maven assembly plugin. I've tried the following ways:

adding two main classes to one manifest

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>CombineMains</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>combineMains</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.fruit.Kiwi</mainClass>
                        <mainClass>com.vegetable.Carrot</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

adding two manifests to one archive

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>CombineMains</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>combineMains</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.fruit.Kiwi</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.vegetable.Carrot</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

adding two archives to one execution

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>CombineMains</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>combineMains</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.fruit.Kiwi</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.vegetable.Carrot</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

using two different executions

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Main1</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>kiwi</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.fruit.Kiwi</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>Main2</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>carrot</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.vegetable.Carrot</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately, these solutions aren't working. The same thing happens for each solution. The second mainClass overwrites the first one. I build the jar like so:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests -P Kiwi -P Carrot
```

and then I run the jar like so switching between the profiles:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=Kiwi target/hugeJar.jar
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=Carrot target/hugeJar.jar
```

what I notice is that the profile that contains the main that was built last is the only one that runs correctly and the other profile doesnt run. if carrot was built last, carrot runs but kiwi doesnt. if kiwi was built last, kiwi runs but carrot doesnt. any suggestions for what i should do?

Comment: why not split it into 2 projects?

Comment: trying to keep the number of components down

Comment: I’m curious... What were you expecting to happen exactly?

Comment: if i run java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=Kiwi target/hugeJar.jar, i expect "kiwis are great!" if i run java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=Carrot target/hugeJar.jar, i expect "carrots are gross!" i have print statements in the two different mains. of course im going to use this for something completely unrelated to kiwis and carrots lol.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html), an executable jar has **one** main class, which is declared in the manifest like so:

```
Main-Class: classname
```

There is no support for, or even concept of multiple main classes.

Your options are:

1. split the project into 3 parts:

   - common stuff
   - main class 1 stuff
   - main class 2 stuff
2. build with 1 main class, but invoke the 2nd main class dynamically `java -cp myjar.jar my.other.MainClass` since the command is already different for both anyway

Comment: @incognitonerd you should accept the answer (you can do so by clicking the checkmark below) if this answer solved your issue.